# regex to check the log prefix

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to check if a log record starts with a log level and log date prefix. Here is an example of log record:

```
[7][20170731 10:36:39:754][18] [just a text] another test
```

Here is what I've tried:

```
//string text = "[7][20170731 10:36:39:754][18] [just a text] another test";
string text = "[7][20170731]";
var pattern = "[\\d{1}][\\d{8}\\s\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{3}].*";

if (Regex.IsMatch(text, pattern))
{
    Console.WriteLine("match");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("not match");
}
```

But my problem is that with the second version of the `text` variable `Regex.IsMatch` returns true even if it's obvious that it's not a match.

So is my pattern wrong?

Comment: A `[` should be escaped when outside of a character class to match a literal `[`. Otherwise, you created a character class with `[...]`.

Comment: You need to escape `[` and  `]` if you want this regex to work

Comment: Indeed, this was the problem. Thanks